# Access number from id in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following menu system. As I add more steps to the menu, I need to write a new function. How do I write a function that will show info for any step? I am thinking of extracting the number in each id and passing it into the function but I'm not sure how to implement. Any help would be great, thanks!

HTML:

```
<h3>
    Step1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <i id="step-info1">Info</i>
</h3>

<div id="step-info-cnt1"
    style="margin-left: 13px; display: none; width: 420px;">
    <div>
        <i id="step-info-close1">Close</i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>info item step 1A</li>
            <li>info item step 1B</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<h3>
    Step2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <i id="step-info2">Info</i>
</h3>

<div class="popup" id="step-info-cnt2"
    style="margin-left: 13px; display: none; width: 420px;">
    <div>
        <i id="step-info-close2">Close</i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>info item step 2A</li>
            <li>info item step 2B</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#step-info1').click(function() {
    $('#step-info-cnt1').show();
});
$('#step-info-close1').click(function() {
    $('#step-info-cnt1').hide();
});

$('#step-info2').click(function() {
    $('#step-info-cnt2').show();
});
$('#step-info-close2').click(function() {
    $('#step-info-cnt2').hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SK8YN/)

Comment: As suggested by Adeneo, you should use class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.id.slice(-1)` gets the number inside the event handler

```
$('[id^="step-info"]').on('click', function() {
    var numb = this.id.slice(-1);
    $('#step-info-cnt' + numb).show();
});

$('[id^="step-info-close"]').on('click', function() {
    var numb = this.id.slice(-1);
    $('#step-info-cnt' + numb).hide();
});
```

and using the "attributes starts with" selector you can select multiple elements.

Using classes does seem more appropriate

```
$('.step-info').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('h3').next('.popup').show();
});

$('.step-info-close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.popup').hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SK8YN/2/)

Comment: doesnt that limit it to a maximum of 10 elements if you use a 0 based index?  If you think my answer below would be sufficient to get the number (using regex), you could incorporate it in your answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @JosephMarikle - You're right, it does limit the number to just one number, so 0-9 only. As for regex, I think I'd probably do `/\d+/.exec(this.id)`, but classes seems like the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to extract it

```
this.id.match(/[0-9]+$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use any number of selectors available to jQuery.

For example, using CSS classes:

```
<div class="step-info" style="margin-left: 13px; display: none; width: 420px;">
    <div>
        <i class="step-info-close">Close</i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>info item step 1A</li>
            <li>info item step 1B</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- and so on -->
```

Your JavaScript would then look like:

```
$('.step-info').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.step-info-close').show();
});
$('.step-info-close').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.step-info:first').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to keep counting.
You can also use classes and target the element you clicked.

Try replacing the ID's with classes and use the following code:

```
$('.step-info').click(function() {
$(this).parent().next().toggle();
});
$('.step-info-close').click(function() {
$(this).parent().parent().toggle();
//alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
});
```

see the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SK8YN/3/